# Confusion about magnetisation through current

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Why are the magnetic domains in the object aligned when the coil that's wrapped around it has current flowing through it. Also why is a magnetic field formed when current is passing through an object?

Comment: the domains are in all directions but they do not get "aligned" in an external field. Instead their sizes shrink or get bigger according to their orientation so that their total *effective* magnetization is changing.

Comment: @hyportnex are you saying that magnetic moments of domains do not align, or that domains do not align? I think that domains can both change size and change direction of their magnetic moment.

Comment: @Jan_Lalinsky you are right, I should have been more precise but most people think that domains are like little compass needles that just spinning around in an external field, they do not.

Answer (score 1):

Torque produce by a magnetic field on a small magnetic dipole(M) is M×B right, when the current is introduced automatically a magnetic field is introduced and therefore due to torque all magnetic dipole try to align themselves in direction of magnetic field produced.